# Model association using includes method to associate 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 main tables linked together via `has_many through:` association.

The main tables are `recipes`, `ingredients`, and `allergens`.
recipes is also linked to `ingredients` through `recipe_ingredients`, and `ingredients` is linked to `allergens` through `ingredient_allergens`.
So in total, there are 5 tables.

What I'd like to be able to do is to see what `allergens` a `recipe` has.

I read the rails documentation and found that I can use the `includes` option to do something similar but in the example the tables are directly associated. see below.

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :book, -> { includes :author }
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :author
 has_many :line_items
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :books
end
```

At the moment my models look like this:

```
# recipes:
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

# recipe_ingredients:
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

# ingredients:
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

# ingredient_allergens:
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :allergen

# allergens:
  has_many :ingredient_allergens
  has_many :allergens, through: :ingredient_allergens
```

I've been trying to use `includes` in a number of ways now but none of them work. Does anyone know if `includes` can even be used in this case? Ideally I'd like to be able to call `recipe.allergens` to see all allergens associated with that recipe.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` is for eager-loading

Try:

```rb
recipe.ingredients.preload(:allergens).map{|ing| ing.allergens.to_a }.flatten.uniq
```

This is straightforward "take all the allergens from all ingredients, put into one array and remove duplicates" and `preload` is to avoid N+1 problem

Comment: this works but i dont quite understand how it works. would you be able to explain it a bit more? thanks

Comment: @Tanpo `map` produces an array of arrays with allergens per ingredient, then that is `flatten` so that it's now a plain array with allergens, but possibly with duplicates that are then removed. These are all standard ruby methods, only magic here is `preload` that makes all this run faster (without it will still work, but query allergens from DB for every ingredient separately)

Comment: awesome! thanks so much for the explanation. I'm quite new to Ruby. didnt know you can use flatten to get rid of arrays within an array. Quite cool.